# Move Memory Associated with Program to Disk

Tags: memory, gpu, process, suspend, pid

I am using PsSuspend to suspend processes by their PID that are using excessive CPU or GPU computational resources whenever I am working on something else and need to have the CPU/GPU working on that instead. However, the memory from these processes that are suspended are left in RAM (or the GPU's VRAM).

Is there any way to write the contents of the suspended program's memory to disk and then free the memory for the operating system in such a way that when the process is resumed, it would read the memory back in from disk and continue as normal? I am interested in achieving this for both system memory (RAM) and video memory (VRAM). I don't think this can be done with PsSuspend, but I suspect it may be possible with Windows APIs and C++. If this is not possible, can you explain why not?

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756405/do-suspended-processes-still-use-up-cpu-ram

> A suspended Win32 process does not release any memory but on a system
> with little free physical RAM, parts of the application can be moved
> from RAM to the page file to free up RAM for use by other active
> applications. SetProcessWorkingSetSize can be called to force a
> reduction of pages in the processes working set.

Perhaps you can use a docker container or VM instead, that way you can suspend/pause the entire workflow and release all the used resources.